# Yamm classic dropdown menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, megamenu

Has anyone use Yamm mega menu to create classic dropdown menu? I'm told to create a drop down menu that is similar to the one on [microsoftstore](http://www.microsoftstore.com/) web site. Is it possible with Yamm? Or there is other libraries that I can use to create one? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used Bootstrap MegaMenu from here.

1) [MegaMenu 1](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-with-tabs-navigation)

2) [MegaMenu 2](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-with-carousel-for-stores)

In that menu there are multiple columns and one carousel slider and no need any external extensions this is pure [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) mega menu.

Comment: Do you have some example codes that you can create multi-level dropdown menu like on the microsoftstore website? I have looked at these bootstrap menus, but I still haven't found a way to at more levels to bootstrap classic dropdown menu.